# IGBT Temperature Drift: How to Achive Stability?

Tags: transistors, stability, compensation, temperature-drift

I remember the BJT transistor circuits are designed to compensate for the fact that the parameters of the transistor change with the temperature.  I could not find similar ready-to-use solutions for the IGBT.  My circuit should work in the switch mode (on/off).  The input signal will be applied to the gate.  Here its DC model (and the transformer for illustration):
[image: DC Equivalent Circuit]

I know I have to adjust *R1* to bias the gate voltage so the IGBT reacts to a small signal.  Here's what gives me the pause.  The specs for the transistor indicate that the bias voltage should be about +6.5 V at room temperature, but this voltage is too much for higher temperatures:
[image: Transfer Curve]

In fact the relation is such that I will have a thermal runaway: the greater the temperature, the greater the average collector current which in turn increases the temperature, and so on.  I expect the collector current to be quite high: 10 A or more (peak value).  What is the easiest solution to compensate for the temperature drift of the transistor?

I am not sure what the purpose of *R3* is; it is a leftover from the original design.  Maybe I can get what I need by adding a capacitor in parallel to it?

Here's the datasheet for the particular IGBT I am using: [Datasheet PDF](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fga15s125p-d.pdf).

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's an IGBT, not an IBGT.

Comment: *BJT transistor circuits are designed to compensate for the fact that the parameters of the transistor change with the temperature* Sure but actually **very few circuits** need that and use that. So **don't** fall into the trap which many inexperienced designers fall into and try to temperature compensate when it is actually not needed. First **prove** that you need it! For a switching application (transistor is either on or off) it is generally not needed.

Comment: The circuit you posted operates the IGBT in analog mode but you said you wanted "switch mode". If you're going to do switching (hard on/off), you don't have to care about the IGBT's transfer characteristics. What exactly do you want to achieve? What is this circuit for?

Comment: Why would you have thermal runaway just because you have negative temperature coefficient?

Comment: don't design around transistor gain, you'll always be dissapointed.

Comment: Are you wanting to run the IGBT in analog mode ? this is no mean feat if you do .

Comment: @JonathanS., I do want the switching mode (complete on or off).  However, I suspect my signal's amplitude at the gate is not enough to put the transistor in ON mode.  Therefore I think  maybe positive voltage bias, close to the where the "paddle" of the "hockey stick" meets its handle, will help.   The transistor is a part of a ~20-40 kHz DC-to-AC convertor (or generator).   The positive feedback signal is provided from the output transformer back to the transistor's gate.  The original design employed a pair of BJTs; being a novice with the IGBTs I didn't realize they need > 10 V to switch.

Comment: Thank you, @Bimpelrekkie.  My knowledge being quite rusty, your information really helps.